# What is the probability that a five-card poker hand has no pairs (possibly straight or flush)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know that the total number of five-card poker hands is $C(52,5)$. I am having trouble figuring our the total number of hands with no pairs, possibly a straight or a flush.

Any hints or help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

- for the first card we have $p_1=\frac{52}{52}$
- for the second card we have $p_2=\frac{48}{51}$
- for the third card we have $p_3=\frac{44}{50}$
- for the fourth card we have $p_4=\frac{40}{49}$
- for the fifth card we have $p_5=\frac{36}{48}$

Comment: are you subtracting $4$ from the numerator each time because of the fact that there are $4$ suits of each value card?

Comment: No the suits but the cards. For example if we select as first card a $K$ for the second card we need to exclude the others $3$ $K$, therefore for the second card we have $48$ good choices among $51$, and so on.

Comment: yes that's what i meant!

Comment: @rover2 Well done! Did you also try by the alternative way presented by 5xum? Bye

Comment: in finishing this problem using your method, i multiplied all those probabilities...is this correct in doing this? @gimusi

Comment: Yes of course, it is the rule of multiplication!

Comment: Why we should not divide $52\times48\times44\times40\times36$ by $5!$?

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way. You can construct the no-pair hand in two steps:

1. Choose the numbers in the hand ($13$ options, you must choose $5$)
2. Order the cards from smallest to largest
3. Pick a color for the first card. Then for the second. Then for the third, and so on.

The middle step is there to ensure you aren't counting anything twice, the number of ways you can perform last step is independent of the first step, so you can just multiply the number of times you can perform the first and last step to get the result.

---

Alternatively, you can use the approach by gimusi in his answer (and for practice, try both approaches which should give you the same answer!)